# SpringBoot 2.x @Inject DTO inside a Controller

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autowired

I'm using `SpringBoot 2.2.6` and I want to know if is it possibile to `Inject` a `DTO` inside my `Controller`. It is a DTO with info coming from various entities..

For example I have a service that build this DTO:

```
@Service
public class SomeService() {
  public ThisDTO getThisDTO() {
    Entity entity = repository.findBySome();
    return transformToDto(entity);
  }
}
```

Now suppose I have a `Controller` like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/Test")
public void TestController {

}
```

I would like to use `ThisDTO` in all method of above `Controller` but I don't want to do something like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/Test")
public void TestController {
  @Autowired
  SomeService someService;

  @GetMapping
  public void method1() {
    ThisDTO thisDTO = someService.getThisDTO();
  }

  @GetMapping
  public void method2() {
    ThisDTO thisDTO = someService.getThisDTO();
  }

  ...
  ...

}
```

but I would like to know if there's a way to do something like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/Test")
public void TestController {
  
   @Inject // or something else
   ThisDTO thisDto;

   ...
   ...

}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Is `repository.findBySome()`  criteria static or dynamic?

Comment: Is a JpaRepository!

Comment: You cannot inject a DTO because it's not a Spring Bean. it also doesn't make sense because the Controller is a Singleton and when you would inject the DTO this will be a singleton as well and never change. But I assume that everytime you call getThisDTO it may have changed on the database

Comment: Yes you're right but in this case that DTO's regarding security. I have a SecurityBean that fill that DTO by retrieving info from DB. Maybe I'm using the wrong approach.. I know there is different way to retrieve Security info by Spring getUserPrincipal ecc.. but I need more info. Than you anyway